# Ansible yaml syntax failure

Tags: ansible

I have a yaml file for ansible

```
  # role: common
  # # common tasks
  # ---
    # #
  # # create default mariadb Audit db users
  # #
 -name: common | setup impactGroup group
 group: name=group system=no gid=510
 ignore_errors: yes
~
```

I also have the proper server list s defined in the inventory file

when i execute the ansible-playbook command i get the following error

```
  /usr/bin/ansible-playbook -D /tmp/eabinay/test.yml -i /tmp/eabinay/dbServerInventory
  ERROR: parse error: playbooks must be formatted as a YAML list, got <type 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

review indentation. This code work for me.

```
- name: common | setup impactGroup group
  group: name=group system=no gid=510
  ignore_errors: yes
```

check first with --syntax-check options:

```
/usr/bin/ansible-playbook -D /tmp/eabinay/test.yml -i /tmp/eabinay/dbServerInventory --syntax-check
```